# « Fais-le pas » — une construction unique à la Romandie ?

Tags: pronoms, négation, régionalismes, suisse, impératif

Je me suis retrouvé à conseiller un voisin ce soir : « Fais-le pas ».

Le français romand a-t-il trop déteint sur moi, ou est-ce que cette construction est connue (ou au moins compréhensible) ailleurs ?

Comment: Comment pourriez-vous imaginer que ce ne soit pas compréhensible ?

Comment: Ça se comprend très bien, mais un conseil : dis-le pas.

Comment: De mémoire, c'est aussi assez commun au Québec: _Embête-nous pas avec tes questions, tabarnak!_

Comment: @Cedric, apparemment (au moins à l'écrit) il y a possibilité de confusion (d'après Colin) ! //J'ai aussi remarqué parfois que là où une tournure de phrase inhabituelle en anglais pousse l'interlocuteur à réfléchir au vrai sens de ce qu'on veut dire, un Français va buter sur la 'faute' et pas pouvoir aller plus loin.

Comment: Un tour du même genre, assez fréquent bien qu'il écorche mes oreilles est « Vas-y pas. » C'est compréhensible sans l'ombre d'un doute, mais ce sera considéré comme un solécisme par beaucoup. À éviter, à moins de savoir ce que l'on fait... « Vas-y pas Gaston / Même si elle te supplie / De l'emmener à la ville / Elle sera ta Manon / Tu seras son Des Grieux / Vous serez deux imbéciles... »

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il y a deux aspects dans ta construction. La suppression du *ne* et l'inversion du pronom avec le verbe.

La forme la plus standard est « Ne le fais pas ! » Une forme orale courante (je ne la qualifierais pas d'incorrecte, simplement d'orale et de familière) est « Le fais pas ! »

Ton « Fais-le pas ! » place le pronom à la même position que dans la tournure de l'impératif affirmatif. Grevisse constate qu'il y a une tendance à adopter cette tournure dans la langue populaire, en particulier au Québec.

Answer (score 3):

Je dois avouer qu'à la première lecture (et même en l'énonçant à voix haute) cette phrase avait pour moi un sens allant dans l'idée de « fais le premier pas ». Sans prêter attention au trait d'union, le sens orignal m'aurait complètement échappé.

Sinon, je pense que ce genre de tournure de phrase est à proscrire, au même titre que les « j'ai pas fait mes devoirs », etc.

Enfin, très personnellement, cette façon de faire une négation me fait autant sourciller que d'autres abus de langage tel que « C'est qui qui ..? » ou « C'est où que ..? », etc.

Ça ne me semble pas naturel de faire disparaître le *ne* sans raison.

Comment: Comment ça, « au même titre que les "j'ai pas fais mais devoirs" » ? Qu'est-ce que tu entends par là ?

Et en passant, pourquoi « c'est qui qui » serait un abus de langage ?

Comment: Les formes correctes sont "Je n'ai pas fait mes devoirs" ainsi que "Qui est-ce qui ..?". Peut-être aurais-je du parler de familiarité plus que d'abus de langage.

Comment: Ici on n'aime pas trop les perscriptivistes :). Dis plutôt que ces formes sont « standards », pas qu'elles sont « correctes ».

Comment: Ce n'est pas très prescriptiviste de commencer ses phrases par _je dois avouer_, _je pense que_, _très personnellement_ et _ça ne me semble pas_. Et puis, dire qu'on n'aime pas les prescriptivistes, c'est très exagéré, à mon sens — même si en effet le site prend une tournure plus descriptiviste (ce dont je me réjouis également), ce n'est pas une raison pour traiter les prescriptivistes comme des pestiférés, ni de voir du prescriptivisme à tous azimuts. D'abord.

Comment: @Joubarc mais c'est qui qu'on critique s'il faut être gentil avec les méchants prescriptivistes qui mangent les enfants ?

Comment: Au lieu de "C'est où que...", on dit quoi ? "Où c'est que..." ? :)

Comment: À la Gaston: _iléou ?_

Answer (score 1):

J'ai souvent entendu « fais-le pas » quand mon professeur de judo disait « fais-le pas tomber. »

Pour moi, cette forme est un solécisme qu'on retrouve dans les couches populaires en France.
À éviter d'utiliser en France.

Comment: « fais-le pas tomber » sonne terriblement mal à mes oreilles. Pour moi, c'est une faute de français évidente.